# What is the name for words which, when the order of letters is reversed, spell other words?

Tags: single-word-requests, orthography

For example:

- Lamina / Animal
- Dog / God
- Ogre / Ergo
- Desserts / Stressed
- Tuba / Abut

These are all anagrams, but they are a special type of anagram, where the order of letters is exactly reversed. They aren't palindromes, as they spell a *different* word when read backwards. I feel like there should be some sort of latin-sounding name for them, but the best I can come up with is the rather imprecise-sounding "backwards words", "mirror anagrams" or "reverse spelling pairs"...

Answer (score 5):

I have seen a couple different terms used for this. The first is [anadrome](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anadrome) and the second, more facetiously, is [semordnilap](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semordnilap). They both mean essentially the same thing: a word (or phrase, as is the case with semordnilap) that spells another word or phrase backwards.